# Problem with trigonometric substitution proof

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm sad, I can't get it. I know perfectly how to integrate using the mechanical process described in the books, but I want to understand the proof of it. My book (Stewart) says:

> In general we can make a substitution of the form $x = g(t)$  by using the Substitution
>   Rule in reverse...
>   $$\int f(x)dx = \int f(g(t))g'(t)dt$$

Is he saying that the function $f$ is now **parametrized** by the function $g(t)$? In this case, integrating with respect to $x$ wouldn't be a simple integration, but instead, it would be a sort of integral with respect to $g(t)$:

$$\int f(g(t))dg(t)$$

Please somebody help me, I can't understand why I can substitute $x = g(t)$.

And yes, I did read the related articles about trigonometric substitution...

Comment: Your observation regarding $\int f(g(t)) dg(t)$ is correct. We call this a Riemann-Stieltjes integral: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral  If $g$ is a nice function (absolutely continuous, to be precise; essentially the condition ensures that $g'$ exists and integrates to $g$), then $\int f(g(t)) dg(t) = \int f(g(t)) g'(t) dt$.

Comment: @Bungo so why no book mentions it in the section about trigonometric substitution?

Comment: We are talking about antiderivatives here. Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$; so, $F'(x)=f(x)$. Then $F(g(t))' = F'(g(t))g'(t)$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @Thursday but when you let $x = g(t)$ then $F'(x) \neq f(x)$

Comment: If $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, then $\frac d{dx} F(x) = f(x)$ always, even when $x = g(t).$ Certainly $\frac d{dt} F(x) \ne f(x) = f(g(t)),$ but that's the point of the chain rule: $\frac d{dt} F(x) = f(x) \frac d{dt} x = f(g(t)) \frac d{dt} g(t).$

Comment: The title has a compilation error, you open parenthesis, but you never close them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila are you serious?

Comment: Yes. Don't use smilies in the title. (And while you edit that part away, make the title more informative.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok, thank you :)